# Adding multiple strings to list<String> simultaneously?

Tags: java

Is there a way to add multiple strings to `List<String>` in a single command?

I know a way of populating `list` as `list.add("string")`, but
 is there  something like `list.add("string1","string2")`?

Comment: Yes, `list.addAll(<another collection of strings>)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is like:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.addAll(Arrays.asList("string1","string2"));
```